# How to solve the recurrence relation $T(n)=aT(n-1)+bn^c$ with $T(1)=1$

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, closed-form, recursion

How to solve this recurrence relation? 
$ T(n)=aT(n-1)+bn^c \\T(1)=1,$ 
 where a, b, c are constant.
I want to solve it using generating function, but get stuck. Could anybody help me?

Comment: This requires computation of $\sum_k a^k k^c$, which I'm not sure exists in closed form. An approximation should help though

Comment: $$\frac{T(n)}{a^n}=\frac{T(n-1)}{a^{n-1}}+\frac{bn^c}{a^n}\land T(1)=1\implies T(n)=a^{n-1}+b\sum_{k=2}^{n}k^ca^{n-k}$$

Comment: The answer can be obtain using Wolfram Alpha, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RSolve%5B%7BT%5Bn%5D+%3D%3D+a+T%5Bn+-+1%5D+%2B+b+n%5Ec,+T%5B1%5D+%3D%3D+1%7D,+T%5Bn%5D,+n%5D - Also see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LerchPhi.html - For example for c=1 see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RSolve%5B%7BT%5Bn%5D+%3D%3D+a+T%5Bn+-+1%5D+%2B+b+n,+T%5B1%5D+%3D%3D+1%7D,+T%5Bn%5D,+n%5D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $c$ is a positive integer,

Solve the homogeneous recurrence first:

$T(n)=aT(n-1)$, which yields the general solution $T(n)=\alpha a^n$

In the case that $a\neq 1$, next assume that $\beta_0+\beta_1n+\beta_2n^2+\dots+\beta_cn^c = T(n)$ and plug that in place of $T(n)$ and $T(n-1)$.

In the case that $a=1$, instead assume that $\beta_0n+\beta_1n^2+\beta_2n^3+\dots+\beta_cn^{c+1}=T(n)$ and plug that in place of $T(n)$ and $T(n-1)$.

In either case, solve for the coefficients $\beta_0,\dots,\beta_c$.

Once done, you may use initial conditions to solve for $\alpha$

---

Example: $T(n)=2T(n-1)+2n$, $T(1)=1$

Homogeneous solution: $T(n)=\alpha 2^n$

Particular solution: $T(n)=\beta_0 + \beta_1 n$

Plugging in: $\beta_0+\beta_1 n = 2(\beta_0+\beta_1(n-1)) + 2n$

Solving by comparing coefficients of powers of $n$: $\begin{cases} \beta_1 = 2\beta_1 + 2\\
\beta_0 = 2\beta_0 - 2\beta_1\end{cases}$

Implying: $\begin{cases} \beta_1 = -2\\
\beta_0 = -4\end{cases}$

Giving a general solution as: $T(n) = \alpha 2^n - 4 - 2n$

Solving for $\alpha$ using initial conditions: $1 = 2\alpha -4-2$, implying $\alpha = \frac{7}{2}$

Final answer: $T(n) = 7\cdot 2^{n-1}-4-2n$

Comment: I know how to solve the recurrence relation if c is a known value. I am wondering if there is a close form for an arbitrary c. [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=F%28n%29%3D%28F%28n-1%29*a%29%2B%28b*n%5Ec%29+%2CF%281%29%3D1) could solve this, but that is not a closed form.