# How to solve ${T(n)=aT(n/2)+bn^c}$, ${T(1)=1}$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, closed-form, recursion

Is it possible to solve a recurrence with constant ${a,b,c}$?

${T(n)=aT(n/2)+bn^c}$ , ${T(1)=1}$

I try to substitute all values of ${a,b,c}$ be ${1}$. But, I can't change back the form with constant.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $n=2^k\Rightarrow\frac{n}{2}=2^{k-1}$

We can transform  $${T_n=aT_\frac{n}{2}+bn^c} \ \text{ with }\  T_1=1$$
to $${t_k=at_{k-1}+b(2^k)^c} \ \text{ with }\  t_0=1$$

Then proceed with your usual methods.
If stuck somewhere, check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626316/how-to-solve-the-recurrence-relation-tn-atn-1bnc-with-t1-1?rq=1) out.